# How to ignore protected pdf's?

Tags: c#, pdfium

I am writing on my pdf-word converter and I just received a really strange exception witch makes no sens to me.

**Error:PdfiumViewer.PdfException:{"Unsupported security scheme"}**

Its the first time that such a exception appears. but I have to be honest that I never tried to convert more then 3-4 files from pdf to word and right now I am doing more then 100 files.

Here is my code I am sry if its too long but I simply do not know on which line the error occurs

```
        public static void PdfToImage()
        {
            try
            {
                Application application = null;
                application = new Application();




                string path = @"C:\Users\chnikos\Desktop\Test\Batch1\";
                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.pdf"))
                {
                    var doc = application.Documents.Add();
                    using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(file))
                    {
                        int pagecount = document.PageCount;
                        for (int index = 0; index < pagecount; index++)
                        {
                            var image = document.Render(index, 200, 200, true);

                            image.Save(@"C:\Users\chnikos\Desktop\Test\Batch1\output" + index.ToString("000") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                            application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\chnikos\Desktop\Test\Batch1\output" + index.ToString("000") + ".png");

                        }
                        string getFileName = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                        string getFileWithoutExtras = Regex.Replace(getFileName, @"\\", "");
                        string getFileWihtoutExtension = Regex.Replace(getFileWithoutExtras, @".pdf", "");

                        string fileName = @"C:\Users\chnikos\Desktop\Test\Batch1\" + getFileWihtoutExtension;
                        doc.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;

                        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inline in doc.InlineShapes)
                        {
                          .....
                        }
                        doc.PageSetup.TopMargin = 28.29f;
                        doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 28.29f;
                        doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 30.29f;
                        doc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 28.29f;

                        application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(fileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument);
                        doc.Close();

                        string imagePath = @"C:\Users\chnikos\Desktop\Test\Batch1\";
                        Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(imagePath, "*.png"), delegate(string deletePath) { File.Delete(deletePath); });
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the PDF is encrypted/secured with a method that Pdfium doesn't support.

Comment: There are some plugins to encrypt PDF files, for example [FileOpen](http://plugin.fileopen.com/) and as @LasseV.Karlsen says, Pdfium seems to not support them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are right there are some pdf that I dont have permission to open ! is there a chance to somehow ignore them in the code ?

Comment: you can put another try-catch block inside `foreach` loop and continue looping when an error occurs.

Comment: @mcy hmm got a example .. or so ? I mean why would that work ?

Comment: @Niko.K in theory it will raise an error within the loop, jump to its own `catch`, and then continue with the next file instead of aborting the whole operation (`pdfToImage` method) as in your code. It will not by any means decrypt. You can add the "skipped/failed" files to a `list` in the inner `catch`, so you can report failed conversions to the user at the end of operation as well.